# Bootstrap table responsive overlaid text

Tags: html, css, web, twitter-bootstrap-3

[image: Smartphone Chrome View]

I want a responsive table that scrolls when over-flow like the responsive bootstrap table was suppose to do.
I'm using this table and why is it not responsive?
All the characters are overlaid on top of each other.

```
<div class="table-responsive">
  <table class="table table-hover table-striped" id="materials-table">
    <thead>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Descritivo</th>
        <th>Qtd</th>
        <th></th>
        <th>Min</th>
        <th>Media <br> P/Instalação</th>
        <th>Fornecedor <br> Habitual</th>
        <th>Ultimo Preço</th>
        <th></th>
    </thead>
   <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>CALHA METALICA EM U 4x4x4</td>
      <td>
         <input type="text" size="1" value="20" class="stock-update"><span> (m)</span>
      </td>
      <td>  <a href=""><i class="fa fas fa-edit" style="font-size:1.5em; color:blue; padding-top:4px"></i></a></td>
      <td>30 <span>(m)</span>
      <td>5 <span>(m)</span></td>
      <td>Gavedra</td>
      <td>14€ <span>p/(m)</span></td>
      <td><a href=""><i class="fa fas fa-cogs" style="font-size:2em; color:blue"></i></a></td>
    </tr>
   </tbody>
  </table>
  </div>
```

Should I change something in the bootstrap class?

Comment: its look like you have mentioned extra css for table somewhere with `table-layout: fixed;`...try to check using web inspect tool

Comment: Do you have a working example online for us to check out? Otherwise its difficult to guess what exactly the problem is...

Answer (score 0):

I simulated your problem with a `max-width` but your markup is working fine (see snippet below).

You can check the following:

- Use your browsers web inspector to check if some of your own styles overwrite styles of the bootstrap classes
- Check if you applied [positioning](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position) rules to the table cells or its content. It seems like they are aligned to positioned parent element.

```css
div {
  max-width: 250px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="table-responsive">
  <table class="table table-hover table-striped" id="materials-table">
    <thead>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Descritivo</th>
      <th>Qtd</th>
      <th></th>
      <th>Min</th>
      <th>Media <br> P/Instalação</th>
      <th>Fornecedor <br> Habitual</th>
      <th>Ultimo Preço</th>
      <th></th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>CALHA METALICA EM U 4x4x4</td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" size="1" value="20" class="stock-update"><span> (m)</span>
        </td>
        <td> <a href=""><i class="fa fas fa-edit" style="font-size:1.5em; color:blue; padding-top:4px"></i></a></td>
        <td>30 <span>(m)</span>
          <td>5 <span>(m)</span></td>
          <td>Gavedra</td>
          <td>14€ <span>p/(m)</span></td>
          <td><a href=""><i class="fa fas fa-cogs" style="font-size:2em; color:blue"></i></a></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```